# Read the lines in a text file after a certain line (c sharp)?

Tags: c#

Let's say I have a text file with this info:

...

Hey

all

this

is

my

question

...

All I want to take are the lines that contain "this" "is" & "my" , I don't know how far they are from the top nor how far they are from the bottom, all I know is that they are in that order and the lines they are surrounded by contain "all" and "question" . I already used a while loop to take everything up to "question", but I don't know how to indicate that it should neglect everything up to "this" (not including it). Could you help me?

Comment: Read the file, use regex to find the lines you want and that's it.

Comment: Can we see your code? There are many ways to do this, but what's probably best is to build off whatever you already wrote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the "easiest" route is to convert the file's lines into a list, and use generic collection methods to do what you want.

```
List<string> AllLines = File.ReadAllLines(yourpath).ToList();

int StartIndex = AllLines.IndexOf(ContainerStartString) + 1;
int EndIndex =  AllLines.IndexOf(ContainerEndString) - 1;
List<string> MyLines = AllLines.GetRange(StartIndex, EndIndex);
```

Answer (score 0):

Been doing it this way for 40 years

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENMAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        enum State
        {
            FIND_HEY,
            GET_DATA,
            FOUND_QUESTION
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENMAME);
            string inputline = "";
            State state = State.FIND_HEY;

            while ((inputline = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                inputline = inputline.Trim();
                if (inputline.Count() > 0)
                {
                    switch (state)
                    {
                        case State.FIND_HEY :
                            if(inputline.ToUpper().Contains("HEY"))
                            {
                                state = State.GET_DATA;
                            }
                            break;
                        case State.GET_DATA :
                            if(inputline.ToUpper().Contains("QUESTION"))
                            {
                                state = State.FOUND_QUESTION;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(inputline);
                            }
                            break;
                        case State.FOUND_QUESTION :
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
​
```